# Converting connected graph to disconnected graph by removing minimum vertices

Tags: algorithms, graphs

How to find the minimum number of vertices that need to be removed from a graph so it makes a disconnected graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum number of vertices that have to be removed in order to disconnect the graph is known at the *connectivity* of the graph. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph#Computational_complexity) outlines an algorithm for finding the connectivity of a graph. More efficient algorithms might exist.

A related problem is the [vertex separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator) problem, in which we want to disconnect two specific vertices by removing the minimal number of vertices.